# capture response of post request in local angular service

Tags: angularjs

Hi i want to capture the response of post request in a local service and wanted to use it in other states can any one help in capturing response of post in local angular service and reuse it in other states of application.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Assign the response to a var in the service

Comment: saveResponse: function(object) {
                    return responses.post('save/'+ id,object);
                }   this is my post request in service         $scope.report = function() {
            responsesService.saveResponse($scope.response).then(function(response) {
                $scope.transactionId = response.assetId;
                             $state.go("reports");
            });
        }; this is code in my controller i need to pass transactionId  to reports page get url

Answer (score 1):

You first define a service with the appropriate functions to retrieve the data:

```
yourApp.factory('tardisFactory',[function(){
    var someData = {'postData':null}
    return {
        retrievePostData: function($http){
            return $http.post("http://apiURL.com",{"data":"cool"}
        }
    }
}]);
```

then, in your controller, you inject the factory (`tardisFactory`) and use the POST response:

```
yourApp.controller('mainCtrl,["$scope","$http","tardisFactory",function($scope,$http,tardisFactory){
    tardisFactory.retrievePostData($http)
        .success(function(response){
            $scope.newVar = response
            //can now use $scope.newVar
        }
}]);
```

You can then inject this factory as you wish into other controllers to use the same post request and data.

Comment: Hi how can i use this in next state  saveResponse: function(object) { return responses.post('save/'+ id,object); } this is my post request in service $scope.report = function() { responsesService.saveResponse($scope.response).then(function(response) { $scope.transactionId = response.assetId; $state.go("reports"); }); }; this is code in my controller i need to pass transactionId to reports page get url